# Is rdstopmgr an AWS RDS user?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, role

I am running postgres on AWS RDS. RDS creates some users on its own, such as `rdsadmin` and `rdsrepladmin`. I am familiar with these

However, I also see `rdstopmgr`, when I query postgres for roles. Google doesn't have much to say about this user, and neither does [AWS RDS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/search/doc-search.html?searchPath=documentation&searchQuery=rdstopmgr). However, I think this may be an RDS user as well.

Here's why: When I Google 'RDS top', I find [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.UsingDashboard.Components.AvgActiveSessions.TopLoadItemsTable.TopSQL.html) from AWS RDS docs. This makes me think `rdstopmgr` may be an RDS controlled user that is used for performance insights.

I've submitted a feedback to AWS requesting they update their docs to include this. However I also wanted to pose this to the community here. Do you agree with my conclusion, or do you know otherwise about this user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html):

> rdstopmgr – A role that's used internally by Amazon RDS to support Multi-AZ deployments.

Comment: Thanks. They added this to the documentation after I submitted my request.